# I'm at the end of my Australia working holiday visa, do I need to leave the country for study visa?

Tags: visa, australia

I'm at the end of my Australia working holiday visa, do I need to leave the country, if I decided to study full time for more than 6 months? But the course will be start after my visa ends. Do I need to leave the country? Do I need a different visa after the end of the working holiday visa and before the study start? If my student visa granted, do I enter bridging visa?

Answer (score 1):

Your [Working Holiday Visa](https://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visa-1/417-) will expire before your intended course of study, you cannot remain in Australia unless you make application for a new, substantive visa.

You would apply for a [Bridging Visa](https://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visi/Visi/Bridging-visas) to allow you to stay while your application for a student visa is being considered.

The Australian Department of Immigration and Citizenship (DIAC) grants a [Student Visa](https://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visa-1/500-) if the course is registered, or part of a registered course, on a full-time basis.